# reading circular seekarc changed each position in android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to android..I created circular seekarc and center i added text for 
showing progress value..My problem while clicking circualar seekarc..how read each
position..suppose starting value is 10 and ending value is 20..i want read each position like 10,11,12,13,14etc..ending value is 20,,from circular seekarc..

```
    seekarc = (SeekArc) v.findViewById(R.id.seekAr);

   seekArcprogres = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.seekArcProgres);

    seekarc.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(
                SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {


            seekArcprogres.setText(String.valueOf(progress + 10));

           }


    @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(
                SeekArc seekArc) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(
                SeekArc seekArc) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried      seekarc.getProgress()  ?

Comment: no...where to add this line in my code

Comment: initialise a global variable    int progress;   and on onProgressChanged  method  write   progress= seekarc.getProgress();     now progress will have required value

Comment: use this it may help you https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar

Comment: inside the method..i can able to add setprogress..if i add getprogress..its showing in red mark

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

take a global variable

```
int  myprogress=0;
```

and

```
 @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(
            SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

         myprogress=progress;

        seekArcprogres.setText(String.valueOf(progress + 10));

       }
```

use myprogress where every you need value

or when ever  you need progress write

```
 seekarc.getProgress();
```

it will return current progress value

if you want to track position 10  ,11

```
   @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(
            SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

        if(progress==10){

         // do your stuff

        }
       else if(progress==11){
        //do your stuff   
        }

        seekArcprogres.setText(String.valueOf(progress + 10));

       }
```